# Rename files based on sorted creation date?

Tags: unix, shell, zsh, batch-rename

I have a directory filled with files with random names. I'd like to be able to rename them 'file 1' 'file 2' etc based on chronological order, ie file creation date. I could be writing a short Python script but then I wouldn't learn anything. I was wondering if there's a clever 1 line command that can solve this. If anyone could point me in the right direction.

I'm using zsh.

Thanks!

Comment: Without wishing to sound picky, I don't believe you can get the file creation date. ctime is the inode change time, which is different to what you want. You can get the modification time, however.

Comment: @Brian Agnew: File creation date is really a feature of the filesytem (although it's indeed quite uncommon on most unix/linux popuplar filesystems). It is featured on most xBSD-based systems (including Mac OS X) and Windows though.

Comment: @ChristopheD - didn't know MacOS supported it. I believe ZFS does as well. But does it manifest itself as ctime ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For `zsh`:

```
saveIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\0'; while read -A line; do mv "${line[2]}" "${line[1]%.*}.${line[2]}"; done < <(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T+ %f\n"); IFS="$saveIFS"
```

For Bash (note the differences in the option to `read` and zero-based indexing instead of one-based):

```
saveIFS="$IFS"; IFS=$'\0'; while read -a line; do mv "${line[1]}" "${line[0]%.*}.${line[1]}"; done < <(find -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T+\0%f\n"); IFS="$saveIFS"
```

These rename files by adding the **modification date** to the beginning of the original filename, which is retained to prevent name collisions.

A filename resulting from this might look like:

```
2009-12-15+11:08:52.original.txt
```

Because a null is used as the internal field separator (IFS), filenames with spaces should be preserved.